# Curve whose signed curvature is $1 / (1 + s^2)$

Tags: curves, curvature, parametrization

> Find a parameterization of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with signed
>   curvature is given by $κ_\sigma(s) = \frac{1}{1+s^2}$.

I have tried to to use [this explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2738431/curve-whose-signed-curvature-is-a-function), but I think I don't have enough information or I am missing something. I have also tried to use the method given by the proof of the fundamental theorem of plane curves. But the resulting integral is not easy, so I think that's not a good way to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the expression
$$
 \beta(s) = \left(\int_{s_0}^s \cos \theta(u)\,du, \int_{s_0}^s \sin \theta(u)\,du\right)
 \quad 
 \text{with $\theta(u) = \int_{s_0}^u \kappa(t)\,dt$.}
$$
The curve $\beta$ has tangent vector $\beta'(s) = (\cos \theta(s), \sin(\theta))$, so it is unit speed parametrized, and its curvature is $\|\beta''(s)\| = \theta'(s) = \kappa(s)$.

The equation gives an explicit expression of the curve in terms of $\kappa$, and mathematically it is equivalent with the method explained in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2738431/curve-whose-signed-curvature-is-a-function) you added (solving the two systems of differential equations amounts to taking an integral twice.)

Here we can work out the integrals. Plugging $\kappa$ in the formula and integrating (with $s_0=0$) gives $\theta(s)  = \arctan(s)$. Now note that
$$
  \cos(\arctan(s)) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}, \quad \sin(\arctan(s)) = \frac{s}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}.
$$
Integrating once again then gives
$$
  \beta(s) = (\mathrm{arsinh}(s), \sqrt{1+s^2}).
$$